# Socket.io not broadcasting to room using redis and webpack example

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, webpack-4

I am trying to create a counter example like the one described in this video:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyFjFcUD4ps

However, I am finding that socket.io only updates windows after setting up the connection. So, I will load the page and the counter will not update on that page, but if I have another window open to the same hash then that page will update.

Here is my client side package.json:

```
  "name": "socketio-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config ./webpack.config.js --inline --hot",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env"
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my index.js file for the client side:-

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:9090');

socket.on('connect', function onConnect() {
    console.log('connected');
    if (window.location.hash) {
        const id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        console.log('hash', id);
        socket.on('stats', function onStats(count) {
            console.log(count);
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
        });
        socket.emit('hello', { 'hashId': id });
    }
});
```

Here is my index.html page:-

```
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hit Counter is <span id="counter"></span></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my webpack.config.json:-

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Here is my server side package.json:-

```
  "name": "socketio-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

And here is my server.js file (ie my server side executable)

```
    const io = require('socket.io')(9090);
    const redis = require('redis');
    const client = redis.createClient();

    io.on('connection', function onConnection(socket) {
        console.log('connected');

        socket.on('hello', function hello(hashId) {
            socket.join(hashId.hashId);

            client.incr(hashId.hashId, onUpdate);
            function onUpdate(err, count) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(count);
                socket.to(hashId.hashId).emit('stats', count);
            }
        });
    });
```

I am running node server.js on the server side and on the client side project I am running npm run start.

I then hit the following URL on different browser windows http://localhost:8080/#asdf

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved my problem. In the code below,

```
const io = require('socket.io')(9090);
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

io.on('connection', function onConnection(socket) {
    console.log('connected');

    socket.on('hello', function hello(hashId) {
        socket.join(hashId.hashId);

        client.incr(hashId.hashId, onUpdate);
        function onUpdate(err, count) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(count);
            socket.to(hashId.hashId).emit('stats', count);
        }
    });
});
```

socket.to(hashId.hashId).emit('stats', count); should be io.to. This was a mistake in my transcribing, not in the original video.